# laravel eloquent search concat condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this 2 tables, one is this table

```
id    field_name     value    record_id
1     first_name     john     1
2     last_name      pencer   1
3     first_name     jame     2
4     last_name      mellow   2
```

I have a $filter_name variable that will look through the child table which can hold either first_name, last_name or both to do filtering, how can I do that? I have tried this

```
$query = $table::with(
                      array(
                            'detail', function($qry) use ($filter_name)
                            {
                                $qry->where('field_id', '=', '1');
                                $qry->where('value', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');

                                $qry->where('field_id', '=', '2');
                                $qry->where('value', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');
                            }    
                           )
                      );

 $query->orWhereHas('detail', function($qry) use ($filter_name){
                        $qry->Where(function($q) use ($filter_name)
                        {
                                $q->where('field_id', '=', '1');
                                $q->where('value', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');

                                $q->where('field_id', '=', '2');
                                $q->where('value', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');
                        }
                   });
```

which just return when searching for first_name, I am not sure how to make it to be able to look through last_name also

Anyone have a good and detailed tutorial on eloquent with relationship nested query(with alot of nested and or) can you please share it also with me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `orwhere` in this case

```
$qry->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');
    ->orwhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');
```

here is the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: I have updated my question. i need to be able to query the field with first_name or last_name

Comment: So whats wrong with my answer? Use `orwhere` to filter for `first_name` or `last_name`. I showed you how.

Comment: the table is actually dynamic, the first_name is not a cell header. instead it is a value inside a cell

Comment: Ok this makes it different. But how can you know which `first_name` belongs to which `last_name` then? The database/table design looks a bit weird to me. Maybe you can explain your design in your question and what you want to achieve by this design.

Comment: I added the record_id into the table, where as the record_id is a foreign key from a parent table with, basically

i am searching for record that will have the first_name of XXX OR last_name of XXX

Comment: Then just query your `value` field: `$qry->where('value', 'like', '%'.$filter_name.'%');` and you don`t have to care about if it is first or last name.

Comment: in your comment, value must be a column name, my column name is dynamic. that is why I need to include the first_name and last_name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66906/discussion-between-peh-and-ponce).